# Using Library LoRa.h with Wemos D1 R2 for Lora Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have been using Lora Shield for communication between server and multiple sensor with arduino . But recently i must save data received to Cloud . So i choose Wemos D1 R2 that have similar board with arduino . But when i upload example code , LoraReceiver can'nt get data . Can Anyone Solve my problem ?

Comment: we have no idea what equipment you are using, how it is connected, what program you are running and what errors you get ... do you think that we can answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you change boards you must also update your pin connections in software.  When you initialize the Lora Shield, you probably specify a few data pins.  Those pin numbers cannot be assumed to remain the same on the new ESP8266 based board.  Furthermore, the ESP8266 board is 3.3v logic while Arduinos are 5v logic so you must ensure that the shield and sensors will also work with 3.3v.